# Installing and Viewing Neo4j on Existing AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j

I'm trying to install the enterprise edition of neo4j on an existing EC2 (Amazon linux) instance. So far I've

wget "link to enterprise"

untar the file

renamed and moved the folder to NEO4J_HOME

then went into the config files for neo4j.properties to make the following changes:

```
# Enable shell server so that remote clients can connect via Neo4j shell.
remote_shell_enabled=true
# The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0 for all interfaces)
remote_shell_host=127.0.0.1
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337
remote_shell_port=1337
```

EDITED Christophe Willemsen pointed out that for my original error, I had forgotten to restart the server at that point but I was still unable to access the web server while it was running. So to make it more clear, I've edited the remaining post:

I went to neo4j-server.properties and uncommented:

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

And start the server

```
NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j start
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [28557]... waiting for server to be ready..... OK.
http://localhost:7474/ is ready.
```

checking the status:

```
NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j status
Neo4j Server is running at pid 28557
```

I can run the shell but the when I go to localhost 7474 I still can not connect

Any help would be appreciative. The only tutorial or help I've found assumed I was starting from scratch with a new instance. If someone could provide some instructions for installing or fix my configuration that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: did you started the neo4j server ?

Comment: also neo4j-shell is not the web interface and make sure to make port 7474 accessible in your firewall configuration

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311222/installing-and-viewing-neo4j-on-existing-aws-ec2-instance) can help you. It also uses Neo4j Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit neo4j-server.properties and uncomment the line with:

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

So that the db listens on an external interface not just localhost, and you have to open the port (`7474`) in your firewall rules.

Make sure to secure access to the db though:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/security-server.html

Comment: Thanks @Michael Hunger, but I already uncommented that. Do I have to configure anything else for my EC2 instance? Does it matter that it have it so only my network can log into it?

Comment: There are firewall rules for the EC2 instance on your AWS console where you have to open the port.